# from kivy.app import App ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy' error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

When I try to run this code:

```
from kivy.app import App

class TheLabApp(App):
  pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

it says:

**line 1, in 
from kivy.app import App
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'**

So what should i do to stop this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I checked in the local environment and got the same problem. When I looked at the sample codes from the main website, I noticed this code.

Can you try this?

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
```

[image]

Comment: Nope not working but thank you for the try

Comment: Did you use the full tag for installation? `pip install kivy[full]` @TharunkeshavBrothers

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the package?

Try the following code in your CMD terminal.

```
pip install kivy
```

Comment: Have you tried it local env? This doesn't seem like a package install issue. I can import `app` when only  I set `kivy.require('2.1.0)`.

Comment: @Tolgahan ÜZÜN I meet another problem about this package today. This and another can run on my vscode when involving "import app".